# (Excel) Trying to store formulas in another cell to make IF() function easier to manage/read

Tags: excel, excel-formula

there.

I have a lengthy nested IF() formula that I want to make easier to manage and read. Instead of ~20 IF statements per cell, I would like to make it 3. To simplify, here is my problem:

```
A1 = a number like 9
A2 = a number like 11
A3 = a number like 5
B1 = IF(A1<5,C$1,IF(A1<10,D$1,IF(A1<15,E$1,F$1)))
B2 = IF(A2<5,C$1,IF(A2<10,D$1,IF(A2<15,E$1,F$1)))
B3 = IF(A3<5,C$1,IF(A3<10,D$1,IF(A3<15,E$1,F$1)))
C1 = Formula 1
D1 = Formula 2
E1 = Formula 3
F1 = Formula 4
```

In reality, all 5 formulas are lengthy nested IF() formulas. I would like to "abbreviate" large chunks of the B1 formula by referencing other cells, but I don't want to drag and fill all 5 columns and calculate 5 answers for every row.

How can I do this?

I have tried INDIRECT but cannot get anything to work. I haven't tried EVALUATE but I would prefer to avoid macros if possible (banned on work computers).

Thank you for your help

Comment: Bases on Excel version, your formula could be simplified. So, post few sample and then show your desired output. Put you current formula. Visitors may have a look give you best solution.

Comment: Compare to a table of values using vlookup() for example